# How to write a switch statement using IAR IDE and STM32 controller

Tags: embedded, stm32, iar

I'm new to the Embedded C programming and working on HAL drivers of STM32F10x devices. I am using IAR IDE and C compiler. The following switch does not seem to work and gives me errors:

```
Error[Pe053]: expected a ":"
```

and

```
Error[Pe065]: expected a ";"
```

at multiple places of the switch statements.

```
    // header file
    #define OUTPUT_GEN_PURPOSE              (uint32_t) 0x00)
    #define OUTPUT_OD                       (uint32_t) 0x01)
    #define OUTPUT_ALT_FUNCTION             (uint32_t) 0x02)
    #define OUTPUT_ALT_FUNCTION_OD          (uint32_t) 0x03)
    #define INPUT_ANALOG                    (uint32_t) 0x00)
    #define INPUT_FLOATING                  (uint32_t) 0x01)
    #define INPUT_PU_PD                     (uint32_t) 0x02)
    #define CNF_POS_BIT1                    (PINPOS[pinNumber] + 2)
    #define CNF_POS_BIT2                    (PINPOS[pinNumber] + 3)
```

```
    // C file
        switch(mode_type)
        {
          // Output Modes
        
        case OUTPUT_GEN_PURPOSE | INPUT_ANALOG:
          port->CRH &= ~((1<<CNF_POS_BIT1) | (1<<CNF_POS_BIT2));
          break;
    
        case OUTPUT_OD | INPUT_FLOATING:
          port->CRH &= ~(1<<CNF_POS_BIT2);
          port->CRH |= (1<<CNF_POS_BIT1);
          break;
    
        case OUTPUT_ALT_FUNCTION | INPUT_PU_PD:
          port->CRH |= OUTPUT_ALT_FUNCTION<<(CNF_POS_BIT1);
          break;
          
        case OUTPUT_ALT_FUNCTION_OD:
          port->CRH |= OUTPUT_ALT_FUNCTION_OD<<(CNF_POS_BIT1);
          break;      
        }
```

Please let me know if there is any issue in switch statements syntax etc.

Comment: the fact that you are using IAR IDE or STM32 controller or that this is embedded is irrelevant to syntax.  You should tag this [C].  The compiler diagnostics are useful.  Do not describe or elide them, copy & paste them verbatim and in full.  They indicate for example the line of code they are reporting, which you have omitted.

Comment: If you get an error involving macros, you have to consider the error in the context of the macro expansion, because that is what the compiler is "seeing" and reporting on.   You might consider the simpler `0x00lu` or just `0x00u`  to `((uint32_t) 0x00)` - no parentheses required.  Or use C++ and say `static const std::uint32_t OUTPUT_GEN_PURPOSE = 0x00u ;` for better type safety and clearer syntax and semantics.

Comment: Don't tell us you made "multiple modifications" then not exhibit those modifications and thier result. The statement contains no useful content. Platitude removed.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
case OUTPUT_OD | INPUT_FLOATING:
```

expands to:

```
case (uint32_t) 0x01) | (uint32_t) 0x01):
```

The parentheses are imbalanced due to error in the macro definitions:

```
#define OUTPUT_GEN_PURPOSE              ((uint32_t) 0x00)
//                                      ^
//                                      Parenthesis
```

The semantics of your `case` constants seems unlikely (and unusual). Did you in fact intend:

```
    case OUTPUT_OD :
    case INPUT_FLOATING:
          port->CRH &= ~(1<<CNF_POS_BIT2);
          port->CRH |= (1<<CNF_POS_BIT1);
          break;
```

meaning *`mode_type` is one of either `OUTPUT_OD` or `INPUT_FLOATING`* rather than the bit-wise OR of the macro values?

With the macro values as they are, it actually does not cause a failure, but semantically the code does not have the meaning you most likely intend, and that will confuse or confound future maintainers, and in other cases may fail.